# how can I display the text without going down I am using .pack() in python

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-layout, tkinter-text

[image: displaying in new line]

labl2 = Label(text=score, font=30).pack()

Comment: is the score 1234?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Create the label only once and then update its text using `labl2.config(text=score)`.  But you need to split the line `labl2 = Label(text=score, font=30).pack()` into two lines: `labl2 = Label(text=score, font=30)` and `labl2.pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling pack() every time you run the function.

try:

```
score = 1

labl2 = Label(text=score, font=30)
labl2.pack()

score = 2

labl2["text"] = score
```